# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dbConnect() on null

Tags: php, pdo

help me please .. whats the wrong in my code.  I try to create login form and verified the input..

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dbConnect() on
>   null

( On  `$this->$db = $this->db->dbConnect();`).

this is connection.php

```
<?php

class connection{

    public $db_host = 'localhost';
    public $db_name = 'login';
    public $db_user = 'root';
    public $db_pass = 'root';

    public function dbConnect()
    {
        try{
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->db_host.";dbname=".$this->db_name,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
           $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }    
        return $this->conn;
    }
}

?>
```

and this is login.php

```
<?php

include_once('connection.php');

class User{

    private $db;
    public function __construct(){

        $this->$db = new connection();
        $this->$db = $this->db->dbConnect();

    }

    public function isAuthenticated($name, $pass){

        if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass)){

            $st = $this->$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM loginUser WHERE username =? AND password =?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $name);
            $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
            $st->execute();

            if($st->rowCount() == 1){
                echo "User Verified";
            }else{
                echo "Incorrect UserName or Password";
            }

        }else{

            echo "Please Enter User Name And Password";
        }

    }



}

?>
```

Comment: You have an extra $ in your references to `$this->$db`

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
    $this->$db = new connection();
    $this->$db = $this->db->dbConnect();
```

with this:

```
    $this->db = (new connection())->dbConnect();
```

And this:

```
$this->$db->prepare
```

with this:

```
$this->db->prepare
```

Actually, in every place you should replace:

```
$this->$db
```

with

```
$this->db
```

Comment: Edited the answer, see again. Just your code was not well formatted.

Comment: its work ... thank you very much